# How check if a windows account is an administrator of pc in vb 2013?

Tags: vb.net, admin

I need to check if the current Logon Windows account is an Administrator of the PC.

```
    If My.User.IsInRole(ApplicationServices.BuiltInRole.Administrator) Then
        'Is Admin
    Else
        'Isn't Admin
    End If
```

This code work fine but if i lunch the code with RUN AS "another account" the code dont do the right job becouse take the account that lunch the code not the Windows account that is logged in.

With this code i can see the current Windows User logged in:

```
    Dim Coll As ManagementObjectCollection
    Dim LogonName As String
    Dim GetName As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")
    Coll = GetName.[Get]()
    LogonName = DirectCast(Coll.Cast(Of ManagementBaseObject)().First()("UserName"), String)
    Dim CleanName() As String = Split(LogonName, "\")
```

So in the string LogonName i'll have the Windows user name account that is logged in but how can i check if is an Administrator?

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function UserIsAdmin(ByVal userName As String) As Boolean
        Dim groupName As String = "administrators" '<--You can localize this'
        Dim isAdmin As Boolean
        Using context As PrincipalContext = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine)
            Dim gfilter As GroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, groupName)
            If gfilter IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim members = gfilter.GetMembers
                For Each member In members
                    If String.Compare(member.Name, userName, True) = 0 Then
                        isAdmin = True
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End Using
        Return isAdmin
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Security.Principle` namespace for this task. I wrote a function in a separate class you can use if you would like or move the function...

This is the class...

```
 Option Strict On
 Option Explicit On

 Imports System.Security.Principal

 Public Class SecurityClass

 #Region "Functions"

  Public Shared Function IsAdministrator() As Boolean
    Dim isAdmin As Boolean = False
    Try
        Dim user As IIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
        Dim principal As New WindowsPrincipal(CType(user, WindowsIdentity))
        isAdmin = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
        Return isAdmin
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return isAdmin
    End Try
  End Function

 #End Region

 End Class
```

To use the class and function, just simply call it where ever needed. I used a messagebox to show it for my test using a button click event.

```
 Private Sub btnIsAdmin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnIsAdmin.Click
    If SecurityClass.IsAdministrator Then
        MessageBox.Show("Current user is an Administrator")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Current user is not Administrator")
    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Don't work... This  code take the profile that execute the program. So if i select RUN AS,this code dont take the Current Windows Login Account but the account that i use in the RUN AS...      If i have the right account in a string,can i check if this string is an administrator account? I mean something like: String.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)